# Selecting a range of photos in gallery

Tags: photos, htc, gallery, htc-one-mini

I have several hundred photos that I want to transfer from my phone to computer. I don't want to manually click each one, is there a way that I can select a range of photos? Similar to how in Windows Explorer you can shift-click one item, then shift-click another item, and every item in between will be selected. I haven't worked out a way to do this. I'm using HTC One Mini, running Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way to move over pictures/albums from your phone to your computer is using a USB cable and connecting your device to your computer. If you have a Windows PC, your device should automatically come up. If you have a Mac. You will need to download a tool called Android File Transfer. I will provide you with the links below.

Anyways, it's really simple. Like I said, if you have a Windows PC. Just connect the device, wait for drivers to load automatically and then open Windows Explorer:

> Start > Run > explorer

And browse through the directories on your device, if your albums are stored locally on your phone and not an SD card. You pictures should be under:

> DCIM\Media\Pictures
>   *This may be different depending on the device*

If you're on a Mac. Use the aforementioned application. Simply download the app, install it, and plug-in your device. Once the application recognizes your phone, you will be able to browse the phone's directories.

[Android File Transfer](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/)

Comment: I did try browsing my phone storage, but for some reason I can't access my main camera uploads folder from Windows. I could transfer the photos to a folder I **can** access, but then that would still require manually selecting every photo, whch I'd sooner avoid.

Comment: Do you get a specific error? If so, please share.

Comment: No, I just can't see the 'camera uploads' folder. I'll post an image when I'm back on my computer.

Comment: @LeoKing That might not be the directory in which the pictures are stored in. Have you inspected all other parent folders within the directory structure? Perhaps it's 1 or 2 folders deep?

Comment: I found the folder, it was in DCIM > 100MEDIA. I can now access all the files.

Comment: @LeoKing So my answer was useful? Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you pointed me in the right direction :). You can have an accept for that.

Answer (score 7):

I found I could multi select pics by touching the first one, holding my finger on the screen, and then dragging across the screen to the last one. They all turn to selected as I pass over them. A bit like selecting text with a mouse on a PC!

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked for selecting a range of contacts as well.

Answer (score 2):

Works also in [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander), an otherwise very clever and powerful two pan file manager: long-tab the icon of the first file, in the menu choose SELECT or DESELECT, glide till the other end of the range, tap the last desired icon, and voila!